# Analysing CDR using opencl parallel progarmming

Tags: mapreduce, opencl, bigdata

I am analysing a large data set of Call Detail Records. I get the details from mysql database and extract user and call duration details and aggregate the sum of call duration of every user.

I allocated 10000000 size output buffer to store output result and invoked kernel with whole data got from mysql database. Within the kernel I used atomic addition to sum up the duration of particular user.

In kernal code

```
 atomic_add(&outputbuffer[userid],duration)
```

It works perfectly.

But I am concerned about the large output buffer allocation. Even to get the result of 100000 data set, we have to go through whole output memory.

Can't we do "Hash map" kind of thing in kernel? How we can use "Map reduce" to this kind of problem.

Whenever I tried this methods, I couldn't avoid collision with parallel processes.

I went through many tutorials and questions in this site related to my problem. But unfortunately I couldn't get any helpful guides.

If any one can suggest idea to solve this problem, It will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the amount of global memory you allocate will be a problem is a function of the number of different users (account numbers, phone numbers ... depending on how you want to summarize the call durations) that your list of CDRs contains and the amount of global memory that your GPU supports.

For example, on a GPU card with 1GB of memory you might be able to allocate roughly 250 million 32-bit counters - probably a bit less. This may or may not be enough to generate duration summaries for your complete batch of call records. If this is not enough, you will have to split your batch in smaller batches. The available amount of global memory can be queried by requesting the `CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE` property using the `clGetDeviceInfo` OpenCL API call.

The problem with using a more complex data structure such as a hash map from the kernel, is that pointers in your implementation on the host side will be meaningless on the device side (OpenCL 2.0 will offer a solution here). So whatever hash map implementation you envision should only use integer offsets from its base rather than pointers. Then there is still the synchronization issue of simultaneous updates to the same value, but there you could use the atomic_add as you do in your original implementation.

Depending on the characteristics of your batch of call data records, you may want to retrieve them sorted by account, source phone number or other key and if there are enough CDRs per key (as would be the case for a commercial customer like a large bank) you could apply a reduction technique such as discussed [here](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/) on the list of CDRs for a given key.

Hopefully this will give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Erik. It's very helpfull.